# Remove item / data from Json file with Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, removechild

I have the following .json file named `weapons.json`:

```json
{
  "weapons": [
    {
      "game": "EMPTY",
      "weapon": "EMPTY",
      "down": "0",
      "up": "0",
      "left": "0",
      "right": "0"
    },
    {
      "game": "DELETE",
      "weapon": "DELETE",
      "down": "0",
      "up": "0",
      "left": "0",
      "right": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

This data is only for testing.

From this file I want to remove the second item :

```json
{
  "game": "DELETE",
  "weapon": "DELETE",
  "down": "0",
  "up": "0",
  "left": "0",
  "right": "0"
}
```

For this, I have tried the following function:

```
#Deleting json info from the selected weapon
def deleteWeapon():
        with open('json/weapons.json') as info:
                weapons_dict =  json.load(info)
        
        for weapon in weapons_dict['weapons']:
                if (weapon['game']=="DELETE" and weapon['weapon']=="DELETE" and weapon['down']=="0" and weapon['up']=="0" and weapon['left']=="0" and weapon['right']=="0"):
                        del weapon
                        
        with open('json/weapons.json','w') as remove:
                json.dump(weapons_dict,remove,indent=2)
                
deleteWeapon()
```

Where I try to do a `del weapon` to remove the value, but this does not work. I have also tried doing `del weapon['XXX'] del weapon['XXX']`
with all item values, but doing this the .json looks like this.

```json
{
  "weapons": [
    {
      "game": "EMPTY",
      "weapon": "EMPTY",
      "down": "0",
      "up": "0",
      "left": "0",
      "right": "0"
    },
    {}
  ]
}
```

Instead of :

```json
{
  "weapons": [
    {
      "game": "EMPTY",
      "weapon": "EMPTY",
      "down": "0",
      "up": "0",
      "left": "0",
      "right": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am grateful to hear any help.

Comment: If any clarification is needed I am awaiting comments.

Comment: Try to use weapons_dict['weapons'].pop(weapon) instead of 'del weapon'

Comment: @Wimanicesir I don't think it's safe to remove items from a list that you are currently iterating. Also I think that `.pop(weapon)` will fail as `weapon` isn't an `int`. I think you meant `.remove(weapon)`

Comment: @Alexci Please remove the `tkinter` tag from the question as the question isn't directly linked to `tkinter`.

Comment: @TheLizzard, already done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
weapons = list(weapons_dict["weapons"])
for i, weapon in enumerate(weapons):
    if (weapon['game']=="DELETE" and weapon['weapon']=="DELETE" and weapon['down']=="0" and weapon['up']=="0" and weapon['left']=="0" and weapon['right']=="0"):
        del weapons_dict["weapons"][i]
```

That iterate over the list using `i` as the current index and then it will call `del weapons_dict["weapons"][i]` when ever it needs to delete that weapon.

Comment: Nope, still don't remove the value.

Comment: @Alexci Btw I fixed the problem.

Comment: Yep, it's fixed, your solution remove data from json, also mine remove data from json and directly from my Treeview.

Answer (score 1):

Already found the solution.

The code should look like this :

```
def deleteWeapon():
        with open('json/weapons.json') as info:
                weapons_dict =  json.load(info)
        
        weapons = list(weapons_dict["weapons"])
        for i, weapon in enumerate(weapons):
                if (weapon['game']=="DELETE" and weapon['weapon']=="DELETE" and weapon['down']=="0" and weapon['up']=="0" and weapon['left']=="0" and weapon['right']=="0"):
                        weapons_dict['weapons'].pop(i)
                        
        with open('json/weapons.json','w') as remove:
                json.dump(weapons_dict,remove,indent=2)
```